# Conditional macro expansion

Tags: c, objective-c, macros, conditional-statements

Heads up: This is a weird question.

I've got some really useful macros that I like to use to simplify some logging.  For example I can do `Log(@"My message with arguments: %@, %@, %@", @"arg1", @"arg2", @"arg3")`, and that will get expanded into a more complex method invocation that includes things like `self`, `_cmd`, `__FILE__`, `__LINE__`, etc, so that I can easily track where things are getting logged.  This works great.

Now I'd like to expand my macros to not only work with Objective-C methods, but general C functions.  The problem is the `self` and `_cmd` portions that are in the macro expansion.  These two parameters don't exist in C functions.  Ideally, I'd like to be able to use this same set of macros within C functions, but I'm running into problems.  When I use (for example) my `Log()` macro, I get compiler warnings about `self` and `_cmd` being undeclared (which makes total sense).

My first thought was to do something like the following (in my macro):

```
if (thisFunctionIsACFunction) {
  DoLogging(nil, nil, format, ##__VA_ARGS__);
} else {
  DoLogging(self, _cmd, format, ##__VA_ARGS__);
}
```

This still produces compiler warnings, since the entire if() statement is substituted in place of the macro, resulting in errors with the `self` and `_cmd` keywords (even though they will never be executed during function execution).

My next thought was to do something like this (in my macro):

```
if (thisFunctionIsACFunction) {
  #define SELF nil
  #define CMD nil
} else {
  #define SELF self
  #define CMD _cmd
}
DoLogging(SELF, CMD, format, ##__VA_ARGS__);
```

That doesn't work, unfortunately.  I get "error: '#' is not followed by a macro parameter" on my first `#define`.

My other thought was to create a second set of macros, specifically for use in C functions.  This reeks of a bad code smell, and I *really* don't want to do this.

Is there some way I can use the same set of macros from within both Objective-C methods and C functions, and only reference `self` and `_cmd` if the macro is in an Objective-C method?

**edit** more information:

`thisFunctionIsACFunction` is determined in a pretty rudimentary way (and I'm definitely open to improvements and suggestions).  Basically it's this:

```
BOOL thisFunctionIsACFunction == (__PRETTY_FUNCTION__[0] != '-' && __PRETTY_FUNCTION__[0] != '+');
```

It's relying on the behavior of the compiler to prepend a '-' or '+' for instance and class methods on Objective-C objects.  Anything else must be a C function (since C functions can't have names that begin with '-' or '+').

I understand that this check is technically a runtime check, since `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` gets replaced with a `char*`, and this is probably the major roadblock to my request for help.

Comment: How do you come up with `thisFunctionIsACFunction`?

Comment: @Artelius edited question with more information

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The preprocessor does all of its work before the actual code is parsed. The preprocessor *cannot* know whether a function is C or obj-C because it runs before the code is parsed.

For the same reason,

```
if (thisFunctionIsACFunction) {
  #define SELF nil
  #define CMD nil
} else {
  #define SELF self
  #define CMD _cmd
}
DoLogging(SELF, CMD, format, ##__VA_ARGS__);
```

cannot work - the #defines are processed before the compilation stage.

So, the code itself must contain a "runtime" check (though the compiler may optimise this out).

I would suggest defining something like

```
void *self = nil; //not sure about the types that
SEL _cmd = nil;   //would be valid for obj-c
```

at global scope; the C functions will "see" these definitions while the Objective-C methods will hopefully hide them with their own definitions.

Comment: +1 Ha!  You're a genius! I never would've thought to define `self` and `_cmd` at a global level!  Thanks! (And it works perfectly; I just tried it.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
if defined "abc" <statement1>
else if defined "def" <statement2>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some sort of macro conditional:

```
#ifndef OBJECTIVE_C
  #define self 0
  #define _cmd ""
#endif
```

I'm not quite sure what you should define `self` and `_cmd` to, those were just guesses.

I'm not sure if there is a predefined macro that you can to check if you are compiling in Objective C so you may need to define `OBJECTIVE_C` manually as part of your build.

Comment: Good idea.  The only problem is that Objective-C is a strict superset of C, which means that ObjC and C can peacefully co-exist side-by-side.  This means that most of my C functions will have `__OBJC__` #define'd.