# ObjC Macros -- can I include check to see if a variable is defined within the current scope?

Tags: objective-c, c, macros, llvm

This isn't the macro that I'm trying to create, but this analogy of attempting to create a custom logging function that works in Obj-C and C contexts illustrates the point:

```
#define Log(_s, ...) do { \ 


/* obviously this won't work as written, */\
/* but it's what i'm trying to accomplish: */\

#if (self && _cmd) /*  \
    LogObjectiveC(_s, ##__VA_ARGS__);  \
#else \
    LogC(_s, ##__VA_ARGS__); \
#endif \
} while (0)
```

In this example, we're trying to consolidate two macros that are used depending on where they are defined.  (`LogObjectiveC` is used when inside an Obj-C method, and `LogC` is used when inside a C function.

Is it possible check for the existence of the 'hidden' arguments (`self` and `_cmd`) inside the Macro definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't possible, because methods, functions and parameters don't exist at macro expansion time. Macros are expanded by the preprocessor before the compiler does anything with your code.

The closest thing I can think of would be to inspect `__func__` at runtime and see whether it starts with "+[" or "-[", since all Objective-C methods start with one of those and no legal C or C++ function can.

Comment: But even if you check if `__func__` starts with `+[` or `-[`, you can't conditionally check the value of `cmd` -- you'll still get a syntax error if that variable isn't in scope.

Answer (score 0):

I'm marking Chuck's as the correct answer, thanks for answering.

After another 15 minutes of googling, I stumbled on this duplicate question:  [Conditional macro expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3031224/conditional-macro-expansion?rq=1)   (which actually goes along the lines of @Chuck's suggestions)